# Action Export_To_File_for_Paginated_Reports failed

Tags: power-automate

I am using **Power Automate** to Export an Excel file from a **Paginated Report** and then emailing that Excel report to a user. It works 100% for small data sets, but when I use a large data set where the Excel file size will be **7mb** I get the below error.

> Http request failed: the server did not respond within the timeout limit. Please see logic app limits at https://aka.ms/logic-apps-limits-and-config#http-limits.

[image]

So I know it's related to the size, but where or how can I increase the size? If I use the "**Subscribe to report**" from Power BI Services it does work for the large data sets.

Answer (score 3):

> Http request failed: the server did not respond within the timeout limit. Please see logic app limits at https://aka.ms/logic-apps-limits-and-config#http-limits.

When these type of issues occur, I would suggest you to use below workaround:

Firstly, you recurrence and then initialize the variable and then inside apply to each call another Power Automate using HTTP call, in another Power Automate flow use the trigger as When an HTTP request is received and the use the pagination(In pagination we can increase the time like below) and other steps like below:

**1st Power Automate Design:**

[image]

**Now in 2nd Flow:**

[image]

Then increase Timeout and then click on done:

Here P1D is timeout for 1 day.

[image]

Then next steps of set email output and send email and etc, this way you can increase the timeout of Power BI Connector `Export_To_File_for_Paginated_Report` and Power Automate apply to each does not fail in first flow.

> So I know it's related to the size, but where or how can I increase the size?

So the above process helps you to increase time.

Alternatively, I would suggest you to use Logic apps as it is the best.

Comment: I do not want to make things over complex by calling 1 Power Automate from another. I appreciate your reply, but yeah I would rather just stick with Logic Apps then.

Comment: Yeah, thats good, if you use logic apps